# Play mp3 file given a url directly to the mp3

Tags: java, android, url, mp3

I want to be able to play an mp3 file in my android application given a url (e.g. http://www.somedomain.com/audio.mp3).

This I think should be used to get a byte array using an InputStream maybe but I'm not totally sure, which then can be used with a MediaPlayer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the SDK pages.
[Playing from a File or Stream](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found in practical life that the MediaPlayer can play just about any MP3 URL
if you take care to reformat any Space characters (0x20) into "%20".
I tried that URLEncoder and some other filters to little gain
but simply converting those spaces before presenting the URL
to MediaPlayer will take you far.

In a String you can easily substitute stuff:

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(urlString.replace(" ", "%20"));